# filter secondary alignments using pysam

Tags: python, pysam

I am new to `python` and trying to learn. The below is an attempt to filter out secondary reads in a `bam` using `pysam`. I ran `mark duplicates` and got an error on several `bam` files due to secondary alignments. I added comments to each line to illustrate my thought process.  Thank you :).

The specific `mark duplicates` error:

```
Value was put into PairInfoMap more than once
```

Here is the script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python  ## call python script
import sys ## import python system functions
import pysam  ## import module

bam = pysam.AlignmentFile(*.bam, "rb")  ## open bam and read
click.echo("Reading BAM file")  ## output message
for read in bam:  ## start loop and iterate over each bam
    if read.is_secondary=true  ## not the primary alignment
    if read.has_tag('XS')  ## look for Secondary Alignment Score tag
        XS = read.get_tag('XS')  ## read and store AS value
    if read.has_tag('AS')  ## look for Alignment Score tag
        AS = read.get_tag('AS')  ## read and store value os XS tag  
    if AS < XS  ## Alignment score less then 
        read.write(read)  ## only print primary alignments
bam.close()  ## end processing
```

Comment: Is there an issue with the script?  If so what is it?  Are you looking for feedback on the script?

Answer (score 3):

Quick look at your script suggests that you are comparing the XS and AS from different reads. I would recommend removing the continue from the `read.has_tag('XS')` continue block.

I think that if you filter out `is_secondary` and `is_supplementary` you don't need to do the XS to AS comparison assuming whatever generated for BAM did so correctly.

```
for read in bam.fetch()  
    if read.is_secondary=true  
        continue
    if read.has_tag('XS') <- This block stores XS and then moves on to the next read
        XS = read.get_tag('XS')  
        continue 
    if read.has_tag('AS') 
        AS = read.get_tag('AS')  
    if AS < XS  <- This block compares the AS of the current read to the XS of the previous read that had one.
        read.write(read)  
bam.close()
```

Comment: I have not tried to executec it as this is my first `python` script i am looking for suggestions. Thank you :).

Comment: I would suggest running the script to determine if it is doing what you want.  What I pointed out above is def a flaw in the logic.

Comment: I ran the script (modified it in the post) and there are many syntax errors... being new to `python` I am not sure what is best... what do you suggest? Thanks :).

Comment: I would start will researching how to write to a file.  `read.write(read)` is not correct syntax.  You will need to open a file and write to that.  Go error by error until you have a working script then determine if the out is correct.